# Change text property of all items in form

Tags: c#

I have many buttons and labels on my c# form. I have a button that changes all butons' and labels' text properties (change language button). Do i have to write all items in click event of button or is there a method that scans all form control items and change their text properties.

There are many other controls that contains labels or buttons. For example a label is added to the control of a panel and when i iterate form controls, i can't reach this label. I want to change all items' text properties at one time.

Thank you.

Comment: What technology for Gui do you use? WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET? Also usually gui frameworks and .net too have some API for localization so you dont need to reinvent it yourself.

Comment: It is surprisingly difficult to explain to a programmer that just finished localizing his app that real users don't change their native language while using their program.  ComponentResourceManager.ApplyResources() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach (Control objCtrl in yourFormName.Controls) {
    if (objCtrl  is Label)
    {
        // Assign Some Text 
    }


    if (objCtrl  is Button)
    {
        // Assign some text
    }
```

}

If a CS0120 error happens, change `yourFormName.Controls` to `this.Controls`;

Comment: CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Control.Controls.get'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ASP.NET's` [`ITextControl` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itextcontrol.aspx) (works similar for Winforms-Controls' [`Text-Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.text.aspx) ):

```
var text = "Hello World";
var allTextControls = this.Controls.OfType<ITextControl>();
foreach(ITextControl txt in allTextControls)
    txt.Text = text;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx

**Edit**: You could easily make it an extension(e.g. ASP.NET, for Winforms replace ITextControl with Control):

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void SetControlChildText(this Control rootControl, String text, bool recursive)
    {
        var allChildTextControls = rootControl.Controls.OfType<ITextControl>();
        foreach (ITextControl txt in allChildTextControls)
            txt.Text = text;

        if (recursive) {
            foreach (Control child in rootControl.Controls)
                child.SetControlChildText(text, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call it for example in this way:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Page.SetControlChildText("Hello World", true);
}
```

This will apply the given text on every child control implementing `ITextControl`(like Label or TextBox).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) property that contains all controls of your form. You can iterate over it:

```
foreach(var control in Controls)
{
    var button = control as Button;
    if(button != null)
        button.Text = Translate(button.Text);
    else
    {
        var label = control as Label;
        if(label != null)
            label .Text = Translate(label .Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i iterate? I have a method like this.

    CsNAddCamButton.Text = SetGUIItemString(GUIItemIndex.CsNAddCamButton);

I am taking strings from xml file.

Comment: control does not have Text property. Should i have to cast it to a type?

Answer (score 0):

If it's `winforms` you should read about `localizing` your application here:

[Walkthrough: Localizing Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using javascript, you can simply go through the DOM and modify the texts of the buttons and labels. Using jQuery this will be very simple

Answer (score 0):

For a web application, you could do this quite easily with jQuery.  Have a look at this:  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$('label').each(function(){this.value = 'something else';});
```

For Winforms, you can use this:

```
foreach (var c in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    c.Text = "TextBox Text";

foreach (var c in Controls.OfType<Label>())
    c.Text = "Label text";
```

But I agree with @ionden, you should consider localizing your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach( Control ctlparent in this.Controls)
    {
      if(ctlparent is Panel or ctlparent is GroupBox)
      {
           foreach(Control ctl in ctlparent.Controls)
{
        if(ctl is Label or ctl is Button)
        {
            ctl.Text= newtext;
         }
    }}
```

This will work.

Comment: This works but i have to iterate all controls in a form, right? Because some of my controls are added to a panel. I think i have to iterate controls in panels, etc.

Comment: you can do this... first iterate through all container controls like panel group box and inside that again write a for each to change button and label.. this will work