# Changing control properties from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying this code to affect all the textbox's in another form

```
//From form2
Principal FrmPrincipal = new Principal();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var control in FrmPrincipal.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)control).Enabled = true;
            ((TextBox)control).Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

But it isnt working, what else do I have to do. Thanks.

@DJ KRAZE Before oppening form2, this code disables all the textboxs of my Principal form and it does work

```
    foreach(var control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)control).Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `Principal`?

Comment: by default aren't the controls set as private..? change  the controls manually to public and then try it..

Comment: Principal is the name of the first form where the textbox's I want to change are, this piece of code is in form2

Comment: Can you define "not working"? I'm guessing it _is_ setting the properties but on a form you've just created and aren't doing anything with.

Comment: Look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10704066/952310

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yes, the controls I want to change its properties are public (Modifiers --> Public)

Comment: @YairNevet Im not familiarized with get-set, I would appreciate if you post an answer with that to solve my problem

Comment: I would suggest changing the code inside of your if condition to do something like this 
`if (control is TextBox)
{
 TextBox tb = control as TextBox;
 tb.Enbled = true;
 tb.Text = string.Empty;
}` 
I would use some sort of recursion as well to make sure that you are setting all of the Textboxes on that form properly

Comment: @DonBoitnott My Principal form is opened all the time and all the TextBox's must be changed when pressing the button from form2 while it is running

Comment: In your click event you are creating a _new instance_ of `Principal` and setting the properties on the controls in _that_ instance. At the end of the method `FrmPrincipal` goes out of scope. Have you loaded a different instance of `Principal` somewhere else in `form2` that you are expecting to be updated?

Comment: You are only working on a *new* instance of a Principal object, which goes out of scope at the end of the method and is never shown.  I suspect you need a reference to the *existing* form that you currently have on the screen.  BTW, if any of those TextBoxes are in a parent container, like a Panel, they won't be reached.  You would have to recursively check any container's Controls collection for more TextBoxes.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Still not working

Comment: show the code of the other form.. you are doing something wrong apparently..

Comment: @petelids Well in fact Principal FrmPrincipal = new Principal() is outside button1_Click, I made a mistake putting it there, in my code it is at the beggining after public partial class form2 : Form, so i dont think that is the mistake

Comment: you are confusing us take a look here ...it's as simple as `1 2 3` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787350/change-text-property-of-all-items-in-form

Comment: The process is simple, I fill some textboxes in Principal form then a button opens form2 but disables all the textboxes first. When pressing a button on form2, enables the textboxes in Principal and clears th texts of all those textboxs

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `form2` from `Principal` and you want to `Disable` all the `TextBoxes` of `Principal` on a button click of `form2`.

To perform this, you must pass the `Principal` reference to `form2` in the `Constructor`.

Example (Calling `form2` from `Principal` form):

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);  //passing "Principal" form reference to "form2"
form2.Show();
```

Changes you have to do in `form2`:

```
Principal FrmPrincipal;             //new object
Form2(Principal principalRef)       //"form2" constructor
{
    FrmPrincipal = principalRef;    //assignment of "Principal" form reference to the new object
}
```

Now you can simply call `FrmPrincipal` anywhere in `form2` and make whatever changes you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it says nullReferenceException in FrmPrincipal. Anyways I will have to look for a workaround to my problem.

Comment: @IsaacTuncarCedron Where does it through the exception ?